# starting tomcat9 from Netbeans 11.2 failed

Tags: java, tomcat

I've installed apache-tomcat-9.0.31 on a linux compter, and I'm using Netbeans ID 11.2. Java Platform version is jdk-13.0.2.

When I'm trying to start the Tomcat Server from netbeans,  but netbeans can't detect, that server is actually started, and continues waiting. "Starting Tomcat 9.0" progress-bar shows till "Starting of Tomcat failed" message appeared. And despite the fact, tomcat is successfully started (it prints "INFO: Server startup in 450 ms" to output window, and tomcat can be accessed at http://localhost/8080), it is not possible either to stop/restart/view tomcat from the server's context menu or to deploy a web app.

here the trace in NetBeans Server Output view

```
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.851 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Version du serveur:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.31
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.855 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Serveur compilé:       Feb 5 2020 19:32:12 UTC
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.855 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Version du serveur:      9.0.31.0
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.855 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Nom de l'OS:           Linux
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.855 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Version de l'OS:        4.15.0-76-generic
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.855 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.855 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Répertoire de Java:     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-13.0.2
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.855 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Version de la JVM:           13.0.2+8
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.856 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Fournisseur de la JVM:            Oracle Corporation
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.856 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/g/genoudph/catalinabase
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.856 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /home/g/genoudph/apache-tomcat-9.0.31
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/g/genoudph/catalinabase/conf/logging.properties
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.867 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande: -Dhttp.proxyHost=www-cache.ujf-grenoble.fr
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.867 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande: -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.867 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande: -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|f203-01
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.867 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.867 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.867 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.867 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.867 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande: -Dcatalina.base=/home/g/genoudph/catalinabase
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.867 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande: -Dcatalina.home=/home/g/genoudph/apache-tomcat-9.0.31
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/g/genoudph/catalinabase/temp
12-Feb-2020 19:11:32.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent La librairie Apache Tomcat Native basée sur APR qui permet des performances optimales dans les environnements de production n'a pas été trouvée sur le java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
12-Feb-2020 19:11:33.095 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initialisation du gestionnaire de protocole ["http-nio-8084"]
12-Feb-2020 19:11:33.128 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load L'initialisation du serveur a pris [433] millisecondes
12-Feb-2020 19:11:33.174 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Démarrage du service [Catalina]
12-Feb-2020 19:11:33.174 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Démarrage du moteur de Servlets: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
12-Feb-2020 19:11:33.184 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Déploiement du descripteur de configuration [/home/g/genoudph/catalinabase/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml]
12-Feb-2020 19:11:33.196 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor L'attribut path avec la valeur [] dans le descripteur de déploiement [/home/g/genoudph/catalinabase/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml] a été ignoré
12-Feb-2020 19:11:33.432 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars Au moins un fichier JAR a été analysé pour trouver des TLDs mais il n'en contenait pas, le mode "debug" du journal peut être activé pour obtenir une liste complète de JAR scannés sans succès; éviter d'analyser des JARs inutilement peut améliorer sensiblement le temps de démarrage et le temps de compilation des JSPs
12-Feb-2020 19:11:33.486 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Le traitement du descripteur de déploiement [/home/g/genoudph/catalinabase/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml] a pris [302] ms
12-Feb-2020 19:11:33.486 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Déploiement du descripteur de configuration [/home/g/genoudph/catalinabase/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml]
12-Feb-2020 19:11:33.557 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars Au moins un fichier JAR a été analysé pour trouver des TLDs mais il n'en contenait pas, le mode "debug" du journal peut être activé pour obtenir une liste complète de JAR scannés sans succès; éviter d'analyser des JARs inutilement peut améliorer sensiblement le temps de démarrage et le temps de compilation des JSPs
12-Feb-2020 19:11:33.562 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Le traitement du descripteur de déploiement [/home/g/genoudph/catalinabase/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml] a pris [75] ms
12-Feb-2020 19:11:33.566 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Démarrage du gestionnaire de protocole ["http-nio-8084"]
12-Feb-2020 19:11:33.580 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Le démarrage du serveur a pris [450] millisecondes
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem on Linux with NB 11.3 and Tomcat 9.0.31 and JDK 13.0.2. After several hours of frustration, on a whim I decided to try downgrading to an earlier version of Tomcat. I picked 9.0.24 for no particular reason. I removed 9.0.31 and re-added the server as 9.0.24.

Everything started working. I have no explanation, except downgrading a few versions worked for me.